# In Microsoft SQL Server, is it possible to speed up Lag() in some way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, lag, windowed

It would seem to be (almost) as easy to scan a table over a clustered index, summarizing a field from the "previous record", as just to summarize that field over the entire table. But no :( Is there anything I can do?

```
create table #Tmp(n int not null primary key)
insert into #Tmp values(0)

declare @k int = 1

while @k < 1024 * 1024 * 32
begin
    insert into #Tmp
    select n + @k
    from #Tmp

    select @k = @k + @k
end

declare @dummy bigint

declare @d1 datetime = GetDate()

select
    @dummy = Sum(Convert(bigint, n))
from
    #Tmp

declare @d2 datetime = GetDate()

select
    @dummy = Sum(convert(bigint, n0))
from
    (
    select
        n0 = Lag(n) over (order by n)
    from
        #Tmp
    ) as Q

declare @d3 datetime = GetDate()

select Convert(time(3), @d2 - @d1), Convert(time(3), @d3 - @d2)
-- 00:00:01.460, 00:00:46.273

drop table #Tmp
```

Comment: The query with the `LAG()` function reads 32 million rows (index entries). It's bound to take some time. What's your expectation in terms of elapsed time?

Comment: @TheImpaler - Presumably to be 1 second rather than 46

Comment: Just for reference I've tried this on my 10 yr old local Dev server and I get `00:00:00.607 00:00:03.297`

Comment: @MartinSmith Still... 46s is quite good, for a 32-million row query. If the OP wants faster performance maybe a cache (refreshed every 5-10 mins) could be used if data does not need to represent the exact up-to-date information.

Comment: But the point is that if scanning the entire 32 million row table and aggregating it takes 1 second why does the LAG take so much longer as it doesn't need to sort anything

Comment: One thing to point out I'm using 2019 and the query executes in Batch mode, using hint `DISALLOW_BATCH_MODE` it takes about a minute so... upgrade to SQL 2019 to take advantage of batch mode.

Comment: I see parallelism for the non-LAG version which when you think about it is an obvious optimization when there's no dependency between rows, and although the final result of the `LAG` version discards any notion of ordering, it appears the optimizer cannot see through that.

Comment: On 2019 localdb I don't see parallelism for either (expectedly) nor batch mode. I only loaded 16 m rows in. And see a 5x difference in elapsed time. Possibly not much that can be done about the timings for the additional execution plan operators  apart from trying to get batch mode https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqLbp.png (on versions before batchmode on rowstore came out there is a trick to do that by referencing a table with a columnstore as  a no-op)

Comment: My 2019 gives me paralellism for the first query and batch mode for both [https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf7Ei.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf7Ei.png). The bulk of the time without batch mode is spent on a Window Spool which is not present for batch mode.

Comment: yeah localdb doesn't support parallel plans so that was expected

Comment: The batch mode window aggregate operator is available from 2016 according to here https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/what-you-need-know-about-batch-mode-window-aggregate-operator-sql-server-2016-part-1 so if the OP can manage to get it should give a good improvement

Comment: @Andrew - what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: The trick with `CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX idx_cs_dummy ON #Tmp(n) WHERE n = -1 AND n = -2;` gave me the batchmode plan and a good speedup https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfhg9.png

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL server prior to 2019 you can utilise some benefits of Batch Mode by creating a dummy table with a *columnstore index*.

Running the window function query on SQL Server 2016 it took 25 seconds:

[image]

However, after creating the following table

```
create table dbo.bmode (Id int not null)
create nonclustered columnstore index CC_BatchModeHack on dbo.bmode (Id)
```

I can include it in the query using an outer join. It actually plays no part in the query at all however tricks the optimizer into selecting *batch mode* for the window function

```
select @dummy = Sum(Convert(bigint, n0))
from (
  select n0 = Lag(n) over (order by n)
  from #Tmp
  left join bmode on 1=0
)q
```

the result is execution time fell to almost 2 seconds

[image]

Answer (score 0):

..for sql2019..

```
select
    @dummy = Sum(convert(bigint, n0)) * (1+APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(n0)-APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT (n0))   
from …
```